# MacOS codesign for java applications, which files should I codesign

Tags: java, macos, codesign

We have a quite big java desktop application (~1.5gb), with again lot's of libraries.
So far, I convert it to a .app bundle for macOS (working without problem)
and I want to notarize this app.
Running codesign with --deep didn't work, and I learned that instead of --deep I should manually apply to codesign command to the individual files.

But my problem is, I don't know which files should I apply to codesign, some blogs I read I should apply everything (like .xml, .png, .properties, .xsd ...)

I wrote a small python script, traverse every file and apply to codesign, (if the file is .jar or .zip it extracts them applies to codesign all files, and then packs them to .jar, .zip again)
but it took so much time, and I'm really confused that should I run codesign command for literally every file (including library jars like slf4j, spring, hibernate etc), or should I run for some specific file types like .jnilib, .dylib and executable binaries?

edit: okey I tried --deep and send for notarization, then of course notarization process send me back a list of errors. I manually apply codesign to these executables

for example the errors were like that:

```json
  "issues": [
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "myApp.zip/myApp.app/Contents/Java/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.30.1/sqlite-jdbc-3.30.1.jar/org/sqlite/native/Mac/x86_64/libsqlitejdbc.jnilib",
      "message": "The binary is not signed.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "myApp.zip/myApp.app/Contents/Java/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.30.1/sqlite-jdbc-3.30.1.jar/org/sqlite/native/Mac/x86_64/libsqlitejdbc.jnilib",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "myApp.zip/myApp.app/Contents/Java/lib/libPDFParser.dylib",
      "message": "The binary is not signed.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "myApp.zip/myApp.app/Contents/Java/lib/libPDFParser.dylib",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "myApp.zip/myApp.app/Contents/Java/lib/libPdfViewerAPI.dylib",
      "message": "The binary is not signed.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "myApp.zip/myApp.app/Contents/Java/lib/libPdfViewerAPI.dylib",
      "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
...
...
```

then for each error, runned codesign (again with -f and --deep flags), but when I try to validate with

```
codesign --verify --verbose=4 "myApp.app"
```

getting these 2 errors:

```
judocu.app: a sealed resource is missing or invalid
file modified: /myApp.app/Contents/Java/lib/libPDFParser.dylib
file modified: /myApp.app/Contents/Java/lib/libPdfViewerAPI.dylib
```

and I'm trying again to sign these two dylib with codesign, but after replacing the signature, again getting same error

```
codesign -f -s "Developer ID Application: myDevIdAcc (MF9Q4L4SBE)" --entitlements entitlements.plist myApp.app/Contents/Java/lib/libPdfViewerAPI.dylib
```

have anyone, any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: How do you have 1.5 gigs in an app?

Comment: resources like images, lots of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this: I run codesign for every error which notarization returns me and doesn't care the errors of codesign --verify,
my process was like this:

- codesign all files in the notarization error log, if it is jar file, extract codesign related file, make jar again, codesign jar file.
- codesign the whole .app bundle with --deep again
- send for notarization

and it worked
I still don't know what particular files should I codesign and what actually --deep does, but I think sometimes codesign --verify can be misleading.